# Boot config.txt is ignored

Tags: raspbian, boot, config.txt, overclocking

## Problem

The `/boot/config.txt` file is being ignored when the Raspberry Pi boots up. As such, overscan and overclocking settings are not taking effect.

## What I've tried

Some reported that the line breaks may be the cause. I checked that there are no Windows-style line-breaks or carriage-returns in the file. All seems to be in order. I even let `raspi-config` generate the file to be sure. And to be extra sure, I also tried putting all the options in a single line, as some suggested on other threads.

Tried updating the firmware by doing:

`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `rpi-update`.

Everything is at the latest. Using `cpufreq-info` showed that overclocking is not taking effect, even with `force_turbo=1`, so the file is definitely being disregarding at boot.

## Technical Info

- Raspberry Pi model: B+
- Image: Raspbian Debian Wheezy (from raspberrypi.org)
- Firmware version: 3.12.28+

## Edit #1

After tirelessly digging deeper, I've found other config.txt files on the Pi. In the `/media` directory, which contains the following 4 subdirectories:

- /media/boot
- /media/boot_
- /media/boot__
- /media/boot___

I edited the config.txt file in each of these four directories with different settings to see which one is being used, and it turned out to be the one in the `media/boot___` directory (last one).

So now the question is, is this normal? If not, is there any way to clean this up so that I have only one `/media/boot` directory?

Also, the other 3 directories give "Permission denied" if I try to `cd` into them. I can if I'm in `su`, but otherwise unable to do so.

## Edit #2

It's also worth mentioning that `raspi-config` modifies the file located at `/boot/config.txt` rather than the proper `/media/boot___/config.txt`

Comment: Could you append an ls -l of the /boot directory and the contents of your config.txt file to your post?

Comment: Check if the boot partition is mounted (`/dev/mmcblk0p1`) and if you're editing the right file.

Comment: @user236012 Thanks for that! Didn't think to look for that. See my updated question.

Comment: Where does this /media directory come from?  Are you editing the SD card in another machine, not on the Raspberry Pi itself?

Comment: No, everything I add/modify is done directly to the Pi itself, either via SSH or VNC.

Comment: I don't know what has happened but you system does not appear to be a standard Raspbian install.  /boot/config.txt is the correct location for the config.txt file.